# Replacing HTML line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace a line like: `<a href="532135412.png" target=_blank>` with  `<a href="./source_files/532135412.png" target=_blank>`.How i can do this using Notepad++ ?

Comment: I am quite sure that there is a lot information missing in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ supports [back-referencing](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) in Regular Expressions, thus:

Find What : `(href=")(532135412.png")`

Replace With : `\1./source_files/\2`

Will transform this:

```
 <a href="532135412.png" target=_blank>
```

Into this:

```
<a href="./source_files/532135412.png" target=_blank>
```

Thus giving you a more powerful and more generic solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `href="` with `href="./source_files/` ? I don't see a need for regex, unless you have further requirements.

**Update**

Then you can use (if you have Notepad v6.x, since from then on there is PCRE regex support)

```
(?<=href=\")([^"]*.gif")
```

and replace with

```
./source_files/\1
```

Comment: I cant replace the href, that would replace every href in my file (not every href from my file needs to be correcter)

Comment: Then you should specify under what circumstances you want to do the replacement.

Comment: An example (from a 4chan thread, cant find a better example): `<a href="1335983744640.gif" target=_blank><img src="./source_tumbs_files/1335983744640s.jpg" border=0 align=left width=251 height=238 hspace=20 alt="68 KB" md5="7qVmd6rJMs4khkDSxUySIg=="></a><a name="1678866"></a>
<span id="nothread1678866"><a href="#6564654" class="quotejs">No.</a><a href="javascript:quote('6564654')" class="quotejs">1678866</a> &nbsp; </span>`.  There i have to replace `<a href="1335983744640.gif" target=_blank>` with `<a href="/source/1335983744640.gif" target=_blank>`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a regex replace to me. It really depends on the contents of your file, but it looks like you can accomplish it with these instructions:

> ```
> CTRL+H to open "Find/Replace dialog"
> Select "Regular Expression" from search mode (bottom left of dialog)
> This is your Find what: href=\"(.*).png\"
> This is your Replace with: href="./source_files/\1.png"
> ```

Comment: Nope, when i try it, it replaces another href... not the good one

Comment: No, it is a good one, but as I said it depends on whatever other context you have in your document. For instance, are you only interested in replacing href's where the value of the href is a series of digits followed by .png? RegExp's can't be developed without looking at an entire document. What I provided was a (working) example, only.